# "I'd like an aisle seat if available" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

My attempt is:

> Preferiría un asiento de pasillo, si disponible.

Is there a better translation, one a native speaker is most likely to say? I would love to know what the most commonly heard sentence would be (even if it's not "grammatically" correct but used in the streets), especially in Mexico.

What if instead of "if available" I had to say, "if one is available"? This sentence:

> I'd like an aisle seat if one is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Preferiría un asiento de pasillo si está disponible
```

... if **it is** available

You can also say

```
Preferiría un asiento de pasillo si hay disponibles
Preferiría en el pasillo si hay asientos disponibles
```